# Go run cannot find package

Tags: go, package

I have a sample project setup based on [this](http://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-labs/labs/next-steps-in-go-code-organization) article.

This is my directory structure:

```
goloang/
└── fooproject
    └── src
       ├── foo
       │   └── foo.go
       └── fooer
           └── fooer.go
```

I have set the `GOTPATH`

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/Bharat/Dev/golang/fooproject
```

I am trying to run `foor.go` but I get a cannot find package error even though it exists in the location referenced by `GOPATH` i.e. in `src/foo`.

This is how I am running it:

```
$ pwd
/Users/Bharat/Dev/goloang/fooproject/src/fooer

$ go run fooer.go 
fooer.go:4:3: cannot find package "foo" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/foo (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/Bharat/Dev/golang/fooproject/src/foo (from $GOPATH)
```

These are the file contents.

`src/foo/foo.go`:

```
package foo

import (
  "fmt"
)

func Bar() {
  fmt.Println("bar")
}
```

`src/fooer/fooer.go`:

```
package main

import (
  "foo"
)

func main() {
  foo.Bar()
}
```

I get the same error when I try to do `go build fooer.go`.

Where am I going wrong with the project structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That might be because of a typo:

```
goloang
instead of
golang
```

You have:

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/Bharat/Dev/golang/fooproject
                  ^^^^^^
$ pwd
/Users/Bharat/Dev/goloang/fooproject/src/fooer
                  ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Aah!! My eyes seem bad. It was really a stupid mistake. Another pair of eyes looking at it was helpful! It works now.

Comment: @Bharat 11PM in SF... I understand ;) I've been there many times.